# Relationship between remainders of shifted polynomials in polynomial divisions.

Tags: polynomials, cryptography

I'm trying to understand a digital communication protocol that is deployed in the European high-speed train balize systems ([link](https://www.era.europa.eu/sites/default/files/filesystem/ertms/ccs_tsi_annex_a_-_mandatory_specifications/set_of_specifications_1_etcs_b2_gsm-r_b1/index009_-_subset-036_v241.pdf)). The goal is to implement such a system in digital hardware.

In this protocol, the concept of polynomial division (which I'm implementing using CRCs) is being used to check for the synchronization of the received message. I'm confused about the math behind one step in this procedure.

$$\begin{align}s_f(x) &= \mathrm R_{f(x)}[v(x)]\\s_f(x)&= \mathrm R_{f(x)}[x^sg(x)]\end{align}$$

where, for any two binary polynomials $c(x)$ and $d(x)$, $R_{c(x)}[d(x)]$ denotes the remainder of the division of $d(x)$ by $c(x)$.  That is, the unique polynomial $r(x)$ of degree less than the degree of $c(x)$ such that $d(x)=q(x)c(x)+r(x)$, for some polynomial $q(x)$. (I'm implementing this division using LFSRs as done in calculating CRC).

Here, $v(x), f(x), g(x)$ are all known values and the goal is to find the value of $s$. I need suggestions on how to do that. I will be calculating $R_{f(x)}[v(x)]$ which will give me a remainder of the order of $f(x)$. Now I need to calculate a value of $s$ such that $R_{f(x)}[x^s g(x)]$ will also yield the same remainder. Note that $x^s g(x)$ is simply an $s$-times left shifted version of $g(x)$ when we deal with the binary representation of these polynomials. I'm also capable of calculating $R_{f(x)}[g(x)]$

EDIT:
The following image show the values of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.Note that $v(x)$ is a cyclically shifted version of $b(x)$ (the n bit message we're finally trying to recover). Further context on the whole problem can be found in the above-mentioned link.

[image]

Comment: Such a value of $s$ need not exist in general; this heavily depends on $f$, $v$ and $o$. Can you include them?

Comment: @Servaes edited the question with relevant information. The long format or short format is inconsequential to the question,  you can just assume the short format.

Comment: Just to be sure (before I waste time answering the wrong question); these are polynomials over $\Bbb{F}_2$? I.e. with coefficients either $0$ or $1$ and such that $1+1=0$?

Comment: You're checking out [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)'s it seems..

Comment: @Servaes yes, it is a polynomial representation of binary numbers so it is 2

Comment: You can always compute the inverse of $g(x)$ and solve the discrete logarithm
$$
x^s \equiv v(x)g^{-1}(x) = h(x)\pmod{2,f(x)}
$$
Since $g(x),f(x)$ are constants the inverse is also a constant. If you can precompute $1,x,x^2,\dots,x^{1022}$ then the discrete logarithm is just a lookup: $h(x) = x^?$
The problem is there may be a simpler, intended solution if these data have some special properties. Note that $f(x)$ is irreducible and $x$ is a generator so for non-zero $g(x),v(x)$ in the "long format" there must be a solution $s$.